# Would like to make my database search more efficent

Tags: java, jpa

Simplified, i have the following three entities:

Project:

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Project {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String name;

  // more attributes

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne
  private Customer customer;
}
```

Customer:

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String name;

  // more attributes
}
```

DailyEntry:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class DailyEntry {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  // more attributes

  @ManyToOne
  private Project project;

}
```

So the project has a customer as an attribute and the dailyEntry has a project as an attribute.

I would like to get all dailyEntries related to a customer. So i need to get all the projects related to the customer first and then get all the dailyEntries related to the projects.

I can achieve that with the following code:

```
for (Customer customer : customerRepository.findAll()) {
  for (Project project : projectRepository.findByCustomerId(customer.getId())) {
    for (DailyEntry dailyEntry : dailyEntryRepository.findByProjectId(project.getId())) {
        // can do sth with all the dailyEntries related to the customer here
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

But achieving that with 3 for-loops seems pretty bad/unefficient, because it has a cubic complexity. Is it really as bad as i think and is there a better way to do it **without** changing the database model?

**Edit**: I tried implementing a `findByCustomer` query inside the `DailyEntryRepository`.

```
@Query("SELECT dailyEntry FROM DailyEntry dailyEntry WHERE dailyEntry.project IN (SELECT pro FROM Project pro WHERE pro.customer.name = ?#{customer})")
List<DailyEntry> findByCustomer(Customer customer);
```

So the query tested in an SQL editor works, but im having problems with passing the customers argument inside the repository. Customer is not an attribute of daily entry, so it does not recognize it. I tried it with the `?#{customer}` annotation as above, tried to use `@Param("customer") Customer customer`, but nothing worked. How can i pass an argument into an SQL query if that argument isnt an attribute of the entity?

Comment: I see the <sql> tag, but where's the SQL?

Comment: Well i thought some SQL script might be a better solution to what im doing.

Comment: Is there a reason for not implementing a CustomerRepository.findAllDailyEntries() method? If you're struggling with that, please tell use what your persistence layer looks like

Comment: To get an SQL query, show us some sample table data and the expected result!

Comment: @Simon I would have to implement that with an SQL query right? But wouldnt that SQL query do essentially the same thing as i did in the java code above? Or is the SQL query more efficient?

Comment: Your SQL query will be much, much faster.

Comment: @Simon would you mind checking the edited comment i posted at the end of the post? Im stuck there right now.

Comment: Alternatively `@OneToMany` might be more efficient than the reverse `@ManyToOne`, lazy or not using List fields.

Comment: From your code, I'd guess your data structure has a relationship DailyEntry -> Project, and Project -> Customer. So your SQL would be "SELECT de FROM DailyEntry de JOIN Project p ON de.projectID = p.ID JOIN Customer c ON p.customerID = c.ID WHERE c.name = ?#{customer}" (or, HQL would by "SELECT de FROM DailyEntry de WHERE de.project.customer.name = ?#{customer}")

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially querying all the `DailyEntry` entities that you have in the database (unless there are entries without a project and projects without a customer). You should use `dailyEntryRepository.findAll()` and retrieve all data with a single SQL query instead of using two nested loops which will result in multiple SQL queries (unless you have setup a cache).